# unable to find some .py files of apps in django project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-apps

I want to ask about how can I access all ".py files" of all apps in my Django project.
Actually, my developer is not responding to me I don't know why the last time he gave me my Django project in zip file. I have installed it successfully in my mac but now he is not responding to me but I have to work on the project by myself so I am worried about my Project.

I have taken a screenshot of my project directory structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRIwP.png)

installed apps portion of base.py file of settings looks like this.

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'polymorphic',
    #'django_extensions',
    'apps.cabinet_extension.apps.CabinetConfig',
    #'cabinet',
    'imagefield',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'nested_inline',
]

PROJECT_APPS = [
    'apps.core',
    'apps.blog',
    'apps.faq',
    'apps.carty',
    'apps.cart',
    'apps.accounts.apps.UserConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + PROJECT_APPS
```

And the URL pattern of urls.py file of azapp looks like this

```
path('super-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view()),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('', include('apps.core.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('apps.blog.urls')),
    path('faqs/', include('apps.faq.urls')),
    path('product/', include('apps.carty.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('apps.cart.urls')),
```

please help me I am so worried about it

Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip properly. It has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: I extract it properly and the project is also working when I run the server but I don't know what is happening here